# diagonalisation of tensors

Tags: tensors

$$H_{(ab),(cd)} =p_{lmno}F_{lm}^{ab}G_{no}^{cd}$$
$$=p_{lmno} \left(n_{do}n_{nc}+\delta_{do}\delta_{nc}\right)\left(n_{bm}\delta_{la}-\delta_{bm}n_{la}\right)$$

Is there a way to diagonalize the above tensor using Mathematica using equation $$P^{-1}AP$$ , how to obtain $P$? $n$ is a real antisymmetric matrix and $p_{lmno}$ is an antisymmetric tensor.

Comment: What does it mean to "diagonalize" a 4-tensor?